# Помогите понять как правильно использовать filter внутри switch

Tags: javascript, html

Здраствуйте, проблема с построением filter внутри switch , есть массив с объектами, мне нужно выстроить фильтрацию товаров , вот мой код, но он не рабочий

```
switch (target.id) {
    case 'all':
        show  = [...goods];
        break;
    case 'new':
        show  = goods.filter(i => goods[i].badge === "новинка")
        break;
    case 'sale':
        show  = goods.filter(i => goods[i].badge === "скидка")
        break;
    case 'low-price':
        show  = goods.filter(i => goods[i].price.current <= 1000)
        break;
    case 'high-price':
        show  = goods.filter(i => goods[i].price.current >= 1000)
        break;
    }
```

Прикрепляю кусочек массива чтоб было понятнее

```
let goods = [
{
    "id": 14,
    "href": "https:...",
    "name": "...",
    "img": [
        {
            "preview": "https:..."
        }
    ],
    "price": {
        "old": 806,
        "current": 549,
    },
    "badge": "новинка"
},
```

внутри show скопирован массив goods который я потом вывожу вместо goods

Comment: Кто такой `target.id`? Откуда он берется?

Comment: `arr.filter(function(item, index, array)` ты его не правильно используешь. https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#filter

Answer (score 3):

Согласно **[документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** первым параметром у колбэка в `filter` находится элемент на текущей итерации (текущий обрабатываемый элемент в массиве.). Поэтому

```
goods[i]
```

не имеет смысла. Ведь `i` это не индекс.

Таким образом все `goods[i]` надо заменить просто на `i`. А лучше если будет говоряще, т.е.

```
....filter(element => element....
           ^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^
```

В итоге будет `element.badge === "новинка"` и т.д.